# Scheduled Task does not run after its creation on Windows 2016 server having parameter "/IT"

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

I am creating a scheduled task as a domain user with the below command written in a batch file (.bat) in Windows 2016 server. The task got created but it is not allowed to run. The same command works on other Windows 2016 server machines or Windows 2012 R2 servers. Only for few Windows 2016 server this seems to be an issue.

```
schtasks /Create /TN RunMethod /TR "%~dp0RunMethod.exe /port=%1" /SC ONCE /IT /RU "%DOMAIN%\%~2" /RP %3 /ST 10:00:00
```

When "/IT" parameter is removed from the above command, it works fine without any issues.
Could someone please help me understand why this difference is coming on different Windows 2016 server where on few machines scheduled task is running fine and on few it does not run??
With the same command it works perfectly fine on Windows Server 2012 R2 too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `/IT` stands for "interactive", is your batchfile waiting for user input?

Comment: I never see any prompt for input. Same runs without any problem on other servers.

Comment: @Dominique my confusion is why it works on other machines and does not work on few? What difference it experiences with /IT?